# AngularJS Performance vs Page Size

Tags: angularjs, performance, pagespeed, bandwidth

My Site is ~500 KB Gzipped including js, css and images. It is built on AngularJS. A lot of people in my company are complaining about the site being slow in lower bandwidths.  There are a few questions I would like to get answered,

1. Is 500KB Gzipped too high for lower bandwidths? People claim it takes 20 sec for it to load on their machine, which I believe is an exaggeration. Is it really due to anugularJS and its evaluation time?
2. How does size of the app matters in lower bandwidths? If my site is 500KB and if I reduce it to 150KB by making a custom framework, Would it really help me in lower bandwidth? If so, how much?

Comment: did you cache the templates ? or does angularjs fetch each template 1 by 1 ? try to bundle your whole application, you should have 2 request: angular.min.js and app.min.js . See gulp template cache

Comment: Lets consider uncached. Since the site is always launched on incognito mode.

Comment: use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-templatecache , it will integrate your templates in js files , no request needed anymore to fetch templates. increase dramatically the startup of app.

Answer (score 1):

It's all subjective, and the definition of "low bandwidth" is rather wide. However...using https://www.download-time.com/ you can get a rough idea of how long it would take to download 500Kb on different bandwidths.

So, on any connection above 512Kbps (minimum aDSL speeds, most are now better than 5Mbps, and 3G mobile is around the same mark), it's unlikely that the file size is the problem.

If "low bandwidth" also implies "limited hardware" (RAM, CPU), it's possible the performance problem lies in unzipping and processing your application. Angular is pretty responsive, but low-end hardware may struggle.

The above root causes would justify rewriting the application using your own custom framework.

The most likely problem, however, is any assets/resources/templates your angular app requires on initialization - images, JSON files etc. This is hard to figure out without specific details - each app is different. The good news is that you shouldn't need to rewrite your application - you should be able to use your existing application and tweak it. I'm assuming the 500Kb application can't be significantly reduced in size without a rewrite, and that the speed problem is down to loading additional assets as part of start-up.

I'd use Google Chrome's Developer tools to see what's going on. The "performance" tab has an option to simulate various types of network conditions. The "network" tab allows you to see which assets are loaded, and how long they take. I'd look at which assets take time, and seeing which of those can be lazy loaded. For instance, if the application is loading a very large image file on start-up, perhaps that could be lazy-loaded, allowing the application to appear responsive to the end user more quickly.
A common way to improve perceived performance is to use [lazy loading](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules).

Comment: makes sense. lets ignore the hardware factor for now. In today's world with the internet speeds, does 500kb really matter to consider lazy loading?

Comment: I've tried to clarify my answer. I assume that the slow start-up speed is due to the code in your 500K app loading additional assets as part of application launch. If that's the case, lazy loading will definitely help. I don't think you'll get much benefit from converting the existing 500K app into lazy loading.

Answer (score 1):

To decrease your load time just process your caching and find the right download tool to calculate the download speed of your file. You can use https://downloadtime.org for reference. If you have any issues let me know. Also to To decrease the page load time try to create chunks of your javascript functionalities which consist only of the functionality which is needed for e.g. the index page to decrease the load time.

Answer (score 0):

As `angular.js` itself has a gzipped size of **57kb** it seems there is much more loaded with this initial page call which is ~10 times the size of `angular.js`.

To decrease the page load time try to create chunks of your `javascript` functionalities which consist only of the functionality which is needed for e.g. the index page to decrease the load time.

For example when you're using Webpack the recommended default maximum file size is around 244kb [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49348365/webpack-4-size-exceeds-the-recommended-limit-244-kib)

[image: Angualr 1.7.5 CDN size minified]