# How can optimize application?

Tags: angular, webpack

I am using angular 12 and webpack 5.

When building a production version, the files weigh more than recommended limit.

> WARNING in entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined
> asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact
> web performance.
>
> Entrypoints:
>
> vendor (1 MiB)
> static/js/vendor.359496346b0a5a782f4a.js
>
> app (509 KiB)
> static/js/app.99781bb2b1b311146d5c.js

What else can you do to optimize?

I don't want to hide the message using  `performance: { hints: false }`.

**webpack.config.prod.js:**

```
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge')
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const commonConfig = require('./webpack.config.common.js');
const ngw = require('@ngtools/webpack');
const path = require('path');

const paths = require('./paths');

const productionConfig = {
    output: {
        path: paths.appBuildPath,
        publicPath: './',
        filename: `${paths.outputJSPath}[name].[contenthash].js`,
        chunkFilename: `${paths.outputJSPath}[id].[chunkhash].chunk.js`
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /(?:\.ngfactory\.js|\.ngstyle\.js|\.ts)$/,
                loader: '@ngtools/webpack'
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new ngw.AngularWebpackPlugin({
            tsConfigPath: path.resolve('../tsconfig.aot.json'),
            entryModule: path.resolve('../src/app/app.module#AppModule')
        })
    ],

    optimization: {
        minimize: true,
        minimizer: [
            new TerserPlugin({
                extractComments: false,
                terserOptions: {
                    parse: {
                        ecma: 8,
                    },
                    compress: {
                        ecma: 5,
                        warnings: false,
                        comparisons: false,
                        inline: 2,
                    },
                    mangle: {
                        safari10: true,
                    },
                    output: {
                        ecma: 5,
                        comments: false,
                        ascii_only: true,
                    },
                },
                parallel: true
            })
        ]
    }
};

module.exports = () => {
    return merge(commonConfig, productionConfig);
}
```

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "webpack-angular",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "build:dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack --mode development",
    "build:prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --mode production"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^12.0.5",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^12.0.5",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-alpha.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-loader": "^2.1.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.1",
    "http-server": "^0.12.3",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.3",
    "typescript": "^4.2.3",
    "webpack": "^5.39.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.7.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.8.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^12.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^12.0.5",
    "@angular/core": "^12.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^12.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^12.0.5",
    "core-js": "^3.14.0",
    "rxjs": "^7.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.11.4"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.common.js:**

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'polyfills': './polyfills.ts',
        'vendor': './vendor.ts',
        'app': './src/main.ts'
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'ts-loader',
                        options: { configFile:  './tsconfig.json' }
                    }, 'angular2-template-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "html-loader",
                        options: {
                            minimize: true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /[\/\\]@angular[\/\\]core[\/\\].+\.js$/,
                parser: { system: true }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ico)$/,
                use: "file-loader?name=[name].[ext]"
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html'
        }),
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
            /\@angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)fesm5/
        )
    ]
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49348365/webpack-4-size-exceeds-the-recommended-limit-244-kib

Comment: @Ikdemm No, it didn't help me

Comment: can you share your package.json. Looks like your vendor file is huge. Are you importing the entire third party library (i.e material or bootstrap etc) instead of using the needed one

Comment: @programoholic Added

Comment: I can't see any other library at all

Comment: use tarser plugin to uglify the code

Comment: do you need ie11 support? Also do you use lazy loading inside of your routes?